# Apache Camel Bindy - can I have a customized data-type for a field?

Tags: apache-camel, datafield, bindy

I have a field that it can have just two values, let us say "A" or "B". If we use FF4J (Fixed format 4J), so we can have a formatter and define an enum for that reason. 
How abount Apache Camel Bindy. 
I do not find anything similar to FF4J formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think Bindy has that supported, but beanio and hence camel-beanio supports adding regex to a field. So you can use regex to restrict values.
http://beanio.org/